# Looping through array of objects - array is fully loaded after first iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

After the first iteration of the `each` loop, `myArr` is fully loaded with all 4 objects. 
(Look in your console for the print out of `console.log(myArr)` – *after* the first loop through).

I am struggling to understand how this is happening, because if you look at the print out of `console.log(item)`, it only contains 1 object, not all 4.

So how is `myArr` getting fully loaded after the first iteration, when that should only be happening after the 4th iteration?

Here is a link to a JSFiddle with the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/fdtom886/

```
var obj = [
    {
        "id": 1111,
        "todoText": {"index":2,"items":[{"firstName":"Benny"},{"lastName":"Hill"}]}
    },
    {
        "id": 2222,
        "todoText": {"index":2,"items":[{"firstName":"Bob"},{"lastName":"Marley"}]}
    },
    {
        "id": 3333,
        "todoText": {"index":2,"items":[{"firstName":"John"},{"lastName":"Lennon"}]}
    },
    {
        "id": 4444,
        "todoText": {"index":2,"items":[{"firstName":"Led"},{"lastName":"Zeplin"}]}
    },
];

var myArr = [];

$.each(obj, function(key, item) {
    console.log(myArr);
    console.log(item);
    myArr.push(item);
});
```

Comment: @Rooster - sorry, but if you look at the 1st print out of `console.log(myArr)` in your JSFiddle, it still prints out a fully loaded array. At least it does on my machine (Chrome). Could you please explain why it does that?

Answer (score 2):

You're logging the array (by reference) to the console. Once you expand it, the each-loop is done, meaning the array itself has 4 items.

To see the difference here, you could log `myArr.length` and you'll see the length is what you'd expect within each iteration of the each-loop.

RE: Your "bonus question" the first print is not blank for me.

Comment: To ditch the reference, you could do `console.log( myArr.slice(0,myArr.length) );`

Comment: Yeah or you could `myArray.toString()` if you just wanted to see a rough representation of what state the array was in then. Either aren't very useful in isolateion.

Comment: So when you say that I'm logging a reference to the array, do you mean that by the time the array appears on the screen, it has already been loaded with all 4 values in the hard drive?

Comment: No. I just mean... Chrome's console displays the *actual* `myVar` variable and allows you to inspect it just like you would within the debugger. Since that variable gets filled in *really quickly*, by the time you actually inspect it- it has 4 items in it. Instead, if you added a `debugger;` statement after you logged, you'd be able to inspect it after each iteration - and you'd see what you were expecting to.

Comment: I'm gonna play with this a bit and think through it. After that if all is good, I'll mark your answer correct. Thanks for the help =)

Comment: Btw, you were right about the "bonus question". I just made a simple mistake in my code.

Comment: Btw, I'm guessing that using breakpoints in Dev Tools would solve this, right?

Comment: Yes, breakpoints would be equivalent to a `debugger` statement, so they would also help give a clearer picture. :)